# Unable to redirect 404 error in jsp

Tags: jsp

Unable to redirect 404 error code to a particular resource. My configuration in web.xml as follows.

```
<error-page>
<error-code>404</error-code>
<location>/FourNotFour.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Please help suggest me in this regard.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should work. Can you please tell us your observations.

Comment: What are you seeing in the screen when you try to test 404?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration looks correct. You can check the existance and location of the `/FourNotFour.jsp`. It should exist immediately inside the context root directory.

```
Context-Dir
   - FourNotFour.jsp
   - WEB-INF
      - web.xml
      - lib
      - classes
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the location of page. The page `FourNotFour.jsp` must be located at root of you web-app (out side the WEB-INF).

Answer (score 1):

Your page should be located in your application and make sure that the FourNotFour.jsp must not have any error. Also check your log file it will help you.